# Can you clear MRU User list in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Hopefully simple question:

How do you clear MRU User list in TFS 2015? This is the list that lets you assign users to tasks from within the web interface.

I see registry entries for other tools but I can't find the entry for TFS.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a simple question if I'm understanding correctly.

1. *Create or edit a new task*
2. *Select a user in the list*
3. *Move your mouse to the **right side** of the user name*
4. *Click red "X" which pops up a dialog with  `Remove from Most Recently Used list`*

[image]

After it, you will not see the user anymore in the MRU list when you create a new task.

Comment: Which version are you using? We are currently on 2015 Update 1. 
Your instructions only work if you delete the current user first. Then you get drop down list with  all the names and the red x appears.

Comment: To clarify this only appears to work when you are editing a work item. Your image shows what appears to be a work item on a 'Board'. in Update 1 it is a simple drop down list. No red x appears. You have to open/edit the work item.

Comment: I was using TFS15 , seems this feature is not available with 2015 Update1 . You can try to update your TFS2015 to update3. Moreover, I'm not sure what' the detail are you meaning. Could you explain more clear or add a screenshot. After remove the user from list, you need to close the web portal and reopen it. It will take effective.

Comment: I tried to create a screen shot but it looked ridiculous after I covered the private info. Suffice to say, the problem is most likely Update 1. We're working on getting to update 3. We have a work around. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: @KevinSedota After test with my *TFS2015 Update3* . This should work for  it. Moreover, if you still could not see red "x" , this maybe related to the ui settings `YOUR PROFILE -- UI SETTINGS-- Theme` change it to **default** and try it again.